# perl not saving variable value outside of if clause

Tags: perl

I am a newbie to perl. Heres my issue:

```
my $monopentime;my $monopenper;my $monclosetime;my $moncloseper;my $monclosed;

if($monday ne "closed"){
 my @monfields = split /-/, $monday;
 my $monopen = $monfields[0];
 my @monopenparts = split / /,$monopen;
 my $monopentime = $monopenparts[0];
 my $monopenper = $monopenparts[1];
 my $monclose = $monfields[1];
 my @moncloseparts = split / /,$monclose;
 my $monclosetime = $moncloseparts[0];
 my $moncloseper = $moncloseparts[1];
 my $monclosed=0;
 print $monopentime;
} else {
 my $monopentime="1";
 my $monopenper="AM";
 my $monclosetime="1";
 my $moncloseper="AM";
 my $monclosed=1;
}
print $monopentime;
```

If you notice I have two print statements, one inside the `ne clause` and one outside the `if else`. when i print the variable `inside` the clause it prints the data but when I print outside the `if else` clause i get nothing.

Like I said im fairly new to perl what is the issue? **I set my variables outside the clause too**

Comment: variables that are declared with [`my`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/my.html) are lexically scoped, meaning they only exist in the innermost enclosing block. In this case that means your `if` and `else` blocks. If you need to access their values outside of these blocks, they should be declared *outside* of your if-statement.

Comment: Variables have a *scope* within Perl.  [http://perlmaven.com/scope-of-variables-in-perl](http://perlmaven.com/scope-of-variables-in-perl). (`my $monopentime` within the curly braces *hides* the `$monopentime` variable declared in the outer scope. Your code is exhibiting expected behavior.)

Comment: @HunterMcMillen That should be an answer, not a comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`my` creates a new variable (scoped to the inner-most block in which it is located). Inside the `if`, you want to assign to the *existing* variable, so drop the `my`.

```
my ( $monclosed, $monopentime, $monopenper, $monclosetime, $moncloseper ); 
if ($monday eq "closed") {
    $monclosed    = 1;
    $monopentime  = "1";
    $monopenper   = "AM";
    $monclosetime = "1";
    $moncloseper  = "AM";
} else {
    $monclosed = 0;
    my ($monopen, $monclose) = split /-/, $monday;
    ( $monopentime,  $monopenper  ) = split ' ', $monopen;
    ( $monclosetime, $moncloseper ) = split ' ', $monclose;
}

print "$monopentime\n";
```

I cleaned up the code at the same time.

- Avoided some needless temporary vars.
- Used the list form of `my` to improve readability.
- Avoided a needless negation in the condition (by swapping the "then" and "else" blocks).
- Used `split ' '` instead of `split / /` for increased robustness. (These are not equivalent.)
- Improved indenting and spacing.
- Moved `$monclosed` to the front/top. It seemed more natural.

Answer (score 3):

[`my`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/my.html) lexically scopes a *new* variable to the current block.

If you run this with `strict` and `warnings` enabled you will get:

```
"my" variable $monopentime masks earlier declaration in same scope.
```

Which means exactly what it says - you're declaring it twice, writing a value into  the one *inside* the block - and then it vanishes at the end of the block.

So basically - remove the 'my' statements around the variables you have already declared at the beginning, and it will work.

And turn on `use strict;` `use warnings;` because that would have told you exactly what the problem is.

Comment: No, you don't get that warning, because the vars are in different scopes. Test: `perl -c -e'use strict; use warnings; my $x; if (f()) { my $x }'` (I wish it did, though!!! It's soooo rare that you'd want to hide a var like this)

Comment: Hmm, I did definitely copy those errors from running `perl -c`. I'll have to backtrack and figure out where they came from.

Comment: You'll get that message when you declare to variables with the sme in name in the same scope (as the message says). Test: `perl -c -e'use strict; use warnings; my $x; my $x'`

Answer (score 1):

Variables that are declared with [`my`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/my.html) are lexically scoped, meaning they only exist in the innermost enclosing block. In this case that means your if and else blocks. If you need to access their values outside of these blocks, they should be declared outside of your if-statement.

[`use warnings;`](http://perldoc.perl.org/warnings.html) and [`use strict;`](http://perldoc.perl.org/strict.html) will also reveal that you are shadowing the definition of `$monopentime` here as well.

Comment: No, `use strict; use warnings;` doesn't reveal the problem. (Test: `perl -c -e'use strict; use warnings; my $x; if (f()) { my $x }'` (I wish it did, though!!! It's soooo rare that you'd want to hide a var like this)